# I am unable to run truffle commands in my terminal after installing truffle on my Mac, the result is always zsh: command not found: truffle

Tags: macos, blockchain, truffle, decentralized-applications

I have node v14.17.0 and npm v6.14.13 installed. Their commands seem to be working fine. I've seen other people with this problem but no clear answer on what should be done within the terminal to recognize the truffle commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
npx truffle init
```